# Receiving results from a different IP address than one input via url requests

Tags: python, authentication, shodan

Can't understand why I'm getting this output:

> Enter IP list filename: nearmeips.txt          216.128.74.178                                  ****                                          <Response [200]>                               {'country_code': 'US', 'country_name': 'United States', 'city': 'Antioch', 'postal': '37013', 'latitude': 36.0595, 'longitude': -86.6592, 'IPv4': '172.58.146.151', 'state': 'Tennessee'}

When 216.128.74.178 is the top of my list of nearmeips.

172.58.146.178 was never passed by me to the site. Here is the code.

```
 
import os
import files                          
import sys                            
import re                             
import time                           
import requests                       
import json                                                                   

file_name = input("Enter IP list filename: ")
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:          
    ip_add = file.readline()    
    print(ip_add,"****")                                                                   
    request_url = 'https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp/' + ip_add    
    response = requests.get(request_url)  
    print(response)  
    result = response.content.decode()   
    # Clean the returned string so it just contains the dictionary data for the IP address 
    result = result.split("(")[1].strip(")")  
    # Convert this data into a dictionary          
    result  = json.loads(result)    
    print(result)
```

I'm using termux in a non-root phone is the only thing I can think of, but I'm new to coding so I'm stumped.

Comment: Cannot see an error in the code, but if you use `'https://geolocation-db.com/json/{ip}` instead you can easily parse the response: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content